# Select next item

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a table like this: 
[image: table]

And i want to select next row after certain playerID where state=1 and if it can't find anything AFTER that playerID start from first row

Expected result:

```
playerID=8 => playerID 13
playerID=15 => playerID 8
```

Right now i'm using sub-query and second query if result is null:

```
function getTargetID($killerID)
{
    $result= $this->db->fetchSingle("
        SELECT playerID FROM targets WHERE state=1 AND 
        ID>(SELECT ID FROM targets WHERE playerID=%u)
        ORDER BY state DESC,ID LIMIT 1",$killerID);
    if(!$result)
    {
        $result= $this->db->fetchSingle("
            SELECT playerID FROM targets WHERE state=1 AND 
            ID>0 ORDER BY state DESC,ID LIMIT 1");
    }
    return $result;
}
```

But i think this code is really ugly and not optimized

Comment: Can you have two state=1 after each other?

Comment: ... Why do you want the "next" `playerId`?  Is there supposed to be some relationship here?  Note that autogenerated ids should be regarded as (highly predictable) random numbers, with no relationship implied.  Is there not supposed to be a relationship, but you just want a stable/predictable selection of a different player?  In which case any other play with a given state should suffice, yes?  You appear to be trying to have the query loop around to the start, which means you don't need a strict "next" id...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I think, player_id is not an autogenerated column.ID is

Comment: yes there can be two or more state=1 after each other.
playerID are users from different table which are randomly put in order using ID(which is Auto increment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing this with nested selects:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce((select playerID
                 from targets t2
                 where t2.state = t.state and
                       t2.id > t.id
                 order by t2.id
                 limit 1
                ),
                (select PlayerId from targets t2 where t2.state = t.state order by id limit 1)
               ) as nextPlayerId
from targets t;
```

You should build an index on `targets(state, id, PlayerId)`.  This index should reduce the subqueries to index lookups -- about the fastest possible way of resolving this query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT playerID FROM targets
WHERE state=1 
  AND ID > (SELECT ID FROM targets 
            WHERE playerID=8)
ORDER BY ID ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes, this would work, i didn't realize that i don't really have to order it by ID and state, but is there any way to cycle to start of the table in single query or do i have to use two queries if first returns null?

Comment: @MarekBeseda You shouldn't rely on the ordering of rows in the table. If you need a specific ordering, use ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this can be done in one query:

```
SELECT Origin.id,
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN Targets.id > Origin.id 
                         THEN Targets.playerId END), -- "after" 
                MIN(CASE WHEN Targets.id < Origin.id 
                         THEN Targets.playerId END)  -- "before"
                ) as nextPlayer
FROM Targets 
JOIN (SELECT id, playerId 
      FROM Targets
      WHERE playerId = %playerId) Origin      
  ON Origin.playerId <> Targets.playerId
WHERE state = 1
GROUP BY Origin.id
```

([genuine SQL Fiddle example!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52140/9))
If you get a null back, then it means there wasn't a valid selection ("nobody here, pops!").

Note that your requirements are to essentially scan the entire table/index.  I'm not sure I have a good way to avoid that in *any* db,  although a window function, `LAG()`/`MIN()` and a good optimizer might help.  Oh, and this version will safely deal with multiple instances of a given `playerId` in the table.

Other than that, what's up with using the "order of the table"?  This isn't in any way guaranteed, and SQL was explicitly created to ignore such things (subverted for performance reasons, but *conceptually* that's the case).

---

## EDIT:

With the requirement of next sequential `playerId`, here's a version I had come up with earlier:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN playerId > %playerId 
                         THEN playerId END), -- "after" 
                MIN(CASE WHEN playerId < %playerId 
                         THEN playerId END)  -- "before"
                ) as nextPlayer
FROM Targets 
WHERE state = 1
```

(and [working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77775/5))

Comment: Order of the table meant the order of IDs or the order of how they were entered in the table. Btw, do i understand it right that it returns null if the only player who's state is 1 is the one i'm selecting from?

Comment: Yup.  I'm assuming you want to avoid selecting the same id over again.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but your code seems to have a problem http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77775/1/0 as you can see playerID=2 selects playerID=10 even though it should select 13. Maybe it's ordered by playerID?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE id > (
            SELECT 
                ID 
            FROM mytable 
            WHERE player_id = 8 
)
AND state = 1
ORDER BY ID ASC
LIMIT 1
```

#### SQL Fiddle Demo

Or alternatively

```
SELECT
  MIN(id),
  player_id,
  state
FROM targets
WHERE state = 1
    and id > (SELECT
                ID
              FROM targets
              WHERE player_id = 8)
```

#### SQL Fiddle Demo

Comment: Your second query will occasionally (or usually) return incorrect `player_id` values, without warning you.  This is because MySQL doesn't require all non-aggregate columns to be placed in the `GROUP BY`.  Which value you actually get depends wholly on the whims of the optimizer, which may change each time the query is run.